# Failing to apply tc filter

Tags: tc, qos

I've run the example at [ifb](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/ifb) both con Centos and on Fedora

```
tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1: protocol ip prio 10 u32  match ip src 192.168.200.200/32 flowid 1:2  action police rate 10kbit burst 90k drop  action mirred egress mirror dev ifb0 
Illegal "action"
bad action parsing
parse_action: bad value (12:police)!
Illegal "action"
```

Is it about a known bug? Any ideas?